# Apply style to fixed div through CSS3 when scrolling down

Tags: css

If you go to [this website](http://answers.yahoo.com) you see that when you scroll down the following style is added through javascript for the top navigation div (`#yucsHead`):

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(73,15,118,1)!important;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(73,15,118,1)!important;
box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(73,15,118,1)!important;
border-bottom: 1px solid #490f76!important;
```

I'm a bit new to CSS3 and noticed that CSS now has many features that you first could only do in Javascript. I was therefore wondering whether this is possible through CSS3 as well. I prefer to do things through css where possible.

Answer (score 0):

For finding how much the document has been scrolled we use scrollTop() in jquery, and based on that styles are applied.Your example site does that...I dont think there is a pure CSS 3 solution for this..